# Customize WooCommerce email per product in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to send a different "Customer New Account" email when a client buys one particular product. After spending a lot of time trying to filter the emails, I think the required code just needs to be added to the customer-new-account.php file.

However, I can't seem to retrieve the order number from that file. Typically, you would reference the order number using:

```
$order->id;
```

But when I add the following code to the customer-new-account.php file, I still can't see the order number:

```
global $order;
printf( __( 'Order ID: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), $order->id );
```

Any ideas how I can retrieve the order details in this file, in order to determine which email to send?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create an if statement on the product buy php, and have it call another php file when that product is ordered. (I'm assuming the person can only order one product, not several. If several, you may need to further filter the data.)

When that product is purchased, the new php file contains a MySQL query to locate that order (type or product number), then send the custom email. The entire email text can be in this new php file as well.

To sum up, you can always query the database to retrieve that info.

I've not used WooCommerce in years, so have no code to look further. It's hard to give more details without seeing more of the code. For me, at least.

Hopefully that helps.